# Using ActiveObjects in JIRA Plugin development in abstractIssueAction

Tags: java, jira-plugin, active-objects

I am using Active Objects in Jira Plugin Development.

For a JiraWebActionSupport created with the webwork plugin module type it works perfectly fine.

```
@Named
public class IssueConfigAction extends JiraWebActionSupport
{
private static final Logger log = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(IssueConfigAction.class);


@ComponentImport
private final ActiveObjects ao; 
private String issueId;


@Inject
public IssueConfigAction(ActiveObjects ao){
    this.ao=ao;
}


@Override
protected String doExecute() throws Exception {

    IssueConfig ic = ao.create(IssueConfig.class);
    ic.setIssueId(issueId);
    ic.save(); 
    return SUCCESS;

}

public String getIssueId() {
    return issueId;
}


public void setIssueId(String issueId) {
    this.issueId = issueId;
}
}
```

But how can i use active objects in any other class like abstract issue action?

```
public class IssueTabAction extends AbstractIssueAction {

@ComponentImport
private final ActiveObjects ao; 

@Inject
public IssueTabAction(IssueTabPanelModuleDescriptor descriptor) {
    super(descriptor);
}

@Inject
public IssueTabAction(ActiveObjects ao) {
    super();
    this.ao=ao;
}


@Override
public Date getTimePerformed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Date();
}

@Override
protected void populateVelocityParams(Map params) {
    params.put("user", ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser().getDisplayName());
    params.put("strings", new String[]{"1","2","3","4"});
}

}
```

I don't know how to inject the constructor correctly?
Or is there a better way to do this?